# Modeling geometric Brownian motion with an Ito process

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am trying to model geometric Brownian motion using `ItoProcess`. I am not sure why I am getting negative values in the output.

I am not using `GeometricBrownianMotionProcess` because I want to model other SDE also.

I am not able to figure out the problem with my  code.

```
r = 33;
s = 8;
sde = 
  ItoProcess[
    \[DifferentialD]z[t] == 
      r z[t] \[DifferentialD]t + s z[t] \[DifferentialD]w[t], 
    z[t], {z, 0.01}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];

sol = RandomFunction[sde, {0, 10, 0.01}];

ListLinePlot[sol, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: `PDF[sde[t]]` and similar look fine. It's possibly a numerical issue due to the huge rate of return you are using, 3300%.

Comment: ^ also the `s` is really high. Try `r = .33; s = 0.1;` instead and it looks more reasonable.

Comment: ^^ thanks! For reasonable values of r and s it is working fine.